# Unable to Connect with SQL Server for Android App in MAUI

Tags: android, sql-server, maui

I am Creating a Test Application for Android & Windows Desktop using Visual Studio 2022, MAUI & .NET 8.0 using SQL Server 2022 as Database, Database and Desktop app is intend to reside on same PC (Local machine on LAN) with wi-fi for Mobile app's to connect with DB.

I am able to Connect with SQL Server & use DML statements if I open the App with "Windows Machine", however If I choose to run it on Android Emulator (Pixel 5 -API 30 (Android 11.0 - API 30)), I get error while Opening Connection saying

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"

my code to Add new Record on xaml page have button to save it.

```
    private async void btnSave_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=SANDEEP-PC\SQL_SANDEEP;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Trust Server Certificate=True";

            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO Users (UserID, UserName, UserPwd) VALUES ({txtUserId.Text},'{txtUserName.Text}','{txtUserPassword.Text}')";

            cn.Open();
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();

            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var toast = Toast.Make($"{i.ToString()} User Saved", ToastDuration.Short, 20);
            await toast.Show(cts.Token);

            txtUserId.Text = txtUserName.Text = txtUserPassword.Text = null;
            txtUserId.Focus();
            
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error..", ex.Message, "OK");
        }       
    }
```

I checked with SQL Server Properties -> Connections -> Remote Server Connection, the option
"Allow remote connections to this server" is already ticked.

so what causing it not to connect?

Comment: Just in case: [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853367/295004) and check the IP Address used in the Android app: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#networkaddresses

Comment: The remote server connection setting is not relevant for this issue. It seems that the android emulator doesn't have access to your local PC name. what does pinging SANDEEP-PC returns

Comment: Change this: "Integrated Security=True", into User/Password connection.

Comment: I created another database on freeasphosting.net, new connection string written with user name and password as

string connectionString = @"Data Source=sql.bsite.net\MSSQL2016;
                          Initial Catalog=sbjakhotya_test; 
                          Persist Security Info=True;
                          User Id=sbjakhotya_test; 
                          Password=asdf@1234";
this too didn't solved the problem, same error is thrown

Comment: I checked, SQL Server Browser is Running in SQL server Configuration Manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Answer for above problem in one of Youtube Video.

I needed Two things to modify to get the Successful Connection

1st : Connection String

Use IP Address of PC where Database resides followed by Port Number & Use SQL Server Authentication.

string connectionString = @"Data Source=192.168.1.123,1433;Initial Catalog=SampleDB;User ID=SQLServerUserNameHere;Password=SQLServerPasswordHere;Integrated Security=True;MultiSubnetFailover=True;Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;Trusted_Connection=false;Pooling=False";

2nd : Port Configuration (very Important)

We need to set TCP Port for all type of IP Addresses type

to do this, Open Sql Server Configuration Manager

From Left Side Items, Select
-> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for NameOfServerInstance

from right side Pane Enable all Protocol Names,

then Select TCP/IP -> Properties
In new window opened (TCP/IP Properties)
Protocol Tab -> Set Listen All Property to Yes

Next

IP Addresses Tab -> Set TCP Port Number for all Entries (IP1, IP2, IP3, IP4, IP5, IP6, IPAll) to Some Number (say default port number 1433) -> Apply -> OK

Reference Video can be seen at (after 16:00 min.)

https://youtu.be/xNmIdFjXzl4?si=75aMvvfPo2kZUCWx&t=960

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).